# Software for making learning from videos more studious, interactive, and effective

Tags: video, chrome, plug-in, social-networks, video-player

This post is a request for software that would make learning from videos found on the web and elsewhere much easier.

Suppose I find an educational video. I watch the video for a while, try to absorb as much as possible, then, someone comes home, and I have to pause it because someone takes over what I am doing. I help the person that came home with the everyday chores. Meanwhile, the video has been paused. When I return to the video, I have forgotten what I was watching and I have to watch it from the beginning all over again. While I watch it, I get bored because I have already seen it. So, after a minute or two, close everything and call it quits. This way, I lose an important learning opportunity, and the video never gets watched completely.

This, must be a common scenario. So, how can we make educational video watching a stronger strength?

I think, what is needed, is the ability to embed the video in a chrome software (such as a chrome plugin), or upload it to a service site (which could use pointers to the original video to stream it without downloading it), that does the following:

While you watch the video, you can click on a button to take a snapshot. The snapshot can then be viewed below the video by scrolling below the video in the same page, in the user's personal video feed. In fact, for each video, each user can upload the video to a special site or page available via a chrome plugin where all viewed videos are found, and, below, you can see the screenshots from the video. For instance, if in the video there is a diagram, you can quickly view that diagram without watching the whole video again, and resume, after pausing or returning to the video later, by just watching the summary of screenshots. Even if the video is watched completely, you can return to the video's page in your own personal space and see the screenshots. Below each screenshot, or even in absence of such screenshots, you can also include comments, explaining what your have seen, and allowing you to not down some personal notes relative to what you have seen, and embed some voice recordings (allowing you to recite what you have seen and listen to it later).

This would mean, that, because you can take pictures, jot down text, embed voice recordings, and return to the content later, the learning is no longer a passive watching but an active process. Forevermore, one that you can return later to and go over at a later time, so as to remember everything quickly at a glance, and allowing you to remember the key points through the voice recordings.

As a bonus, clicking on each screenshot could take you back to the whereabouts of that site in the video where the image was encountered and play more.

It would also be great if the software could be directed to extract all text of the video and display it (which may or may not be useful as the video may contain diagrams, but the user may nevertheless want to go over it (and there may be even since areas where the user cannot hear properly the voice from the video, and going through the text might help)).

If, the site were a service site, where each user could have their personal space, and also share their study session, if wanted, for each video (of really desired), then that would be great.

I am looking for a software that does this. It would be fabulous. A Chrome Plugin for remembering videos found on the web that also integrated the list of watched web videos and for each video also the comments and audio recordings into Google Drive would be great.

In the future, the Chrome Plugin could be integrated into a whole site that kept track of both web content videos and YouTube content videos, while offering study space (in the form described), and social sharing of study sessions, when desired.

Where can I find such a software?

Thanks.

Comment: This is why we used to have printed manuals & course study books. They do exactly what you want with only a pencil.

Comment: Yes but that means I have to waste prayer and purchase books which may furthermore not expose the material in the same way. Nowadays people learn from videos and we must cater to better learning from them.